# Paracol break corresponding columns at pagebreak

Tags: page-breaking, polyglossia, widows-orphans

In general `paracol` respect synchronization between two corresponding columns also when it reach bottom page. But sometimes, it occur an absolute ugly orphan (and also widow) when a left side stay in previous page and right side in next page. In addition to orphan-widow effect, a blank side happens next to each part.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Ligatures=TeX,Script=Arabic,Scale=1.4]{Scheherazade}





\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

 \switchcolumn*
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, }
 \switchcolumn
\textarabic{من المهم الاهتمام بالألم نفسه ، وسيتبعه نمو المريض ، ولكن في نفس الوقت سيحدث الكثير من العمل والألم.}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

As example, with this MWE (sorry for the length, but I made many try to get the target behavior), a line is dispatched between the page 3 and 4:

[image: Rendering]

The right part start at the end of the page 3 and finish at the page 4. In the same time, the left part start only at the page 4 and remain an ugly gap in front of the right part.

### The question

How to force every line dispatched between to pages, to fully started at the next page instead of be cut?

Comment: BTW, when testing end of page effects, I like to use something llike `\rule{1pt}{25\baselineskip}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the font, but adding

```
\interlinepenalty=10000
```

to your preamble will mean tex only breaks a page between paragraphs.